# Finding matrix representation of linear transformation - intuition

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, intuition

Given a linear transformation $t : V \longrightarrow W$, we want to find a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ that represents this linear transformation.

I already have seen examples how this is done, but I'd like to improve my intuitive understanding of linear algebra, instead of following a predefined set of steps.

1. So, in general, I understood that a given linear transformation, when applied to a vector space, is completely defined by where the basis vectors of the vector space go.
2. I also understood that there can be four cases when we want to find the matrix representation of a given linear transformation $t : V \longrightarrow W$.

| Case | Base of domain $V$ | Base of codomain $W$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | standard | standard |
| 2 | non-standard | standard |
| 3 | standard | non-standard |
| 4 | non-standard | non-standard |

- For any case, to find the matrix representation of of $t$, we apply $t$ to the basis of the domain $V$.
- For case 1 and 2, we are then done and can use these results of applying $t$ to the basis vectors of $V$ to create $\mathbf{A}$ column-wise.
- For case 3 and 4, we have some more work to do and need to translate the images under $t$ of the  base vectors of the domain $V$ into the base of codomain $W$. After that, based on these results, create $\mathbf{A}$ column-wise.

I get that for case 1 we don't need to do any translation, since domain and codomain have the same standard base. What's not intuitive to me: Why we don't need to do any translation in case of 2?

Example for case 2 from a book I have:

> - Let $t : \mathbb{R}^3 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ with the rule $(x, y, z) \mapsto (x, y)$. Let the domain have the non-standard basis $E=\{(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0)\}$ and the codomain have the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$.
> - Then: $t(1, 1, 1) = \color{red}{(1, 1)}$ and $t(1, 1, 0) = \color{blue}{(1, 1)}$ and $t(1, 0, 0) = \color{green}{(1, 0)}$. Hence the matrix of $t$ with respect to the bases $E$ and $F$ is given by:
>
> $$
> \mathbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix}
> \color{red}{1} & \color{blue}{1} & \color{green}{1} \\ 
> \color{red}{1} & \color{blue}{1} & \color{green}{0}
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$

I find this curious that we don't need to translate the images under $t$ of the basis vectors of the domain $V$ into the basis of the codomain $W$ - because to my understanding, the images of the basis vectors of $V$ under $t$ would be still be using the basis of $V$? Or is my understanding here incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All those four cases are really just 1 case. Given vector space $U$ with basis $B = \{u_1, \dots, u_n\}$, define the coordinate isomorphism $J_B \colon \mathbb{F}^n \to U$ by
$$J_Be_j = u_j \text{ for each } j \in \{1, \dots, n\}.$$

Suppose $T \colon V \to W$ is linear, $B_1 = \{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$, and $B_2 = \{w_1, \dots, w_m\}$ is a basis of $W$. Then the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to these bases is
$$M_{B_1}^{B_2}(T) = J_{B_2}^{-1}TJ_{B_1}.$$
So $M_{B_1}^{B_2}(T)$ takes in $B_1$-coordinates of a vector $v \in V$ and returns $B_2$-coordinates of $Tv$. Thus the $j$-th column of $M_{B_1}^{B_2}(T)$ is the $B_2$-coordinates of $Tv_j$.

Comment: I think I get the second part of your answer, but I'm not fully clear on what $J_B$ does.  As far as I can understand $u_j$ is a basis vector of basis $B$. What's $e_j$? You mention $J_B$ is a coordinate isomorphism, so it's a bijection between coordinates. But I don't follow what the mapping rule is.

Comment: I agree though that it makes sense to fold all 4 cases into a single one.

Comment: @Max I meant to say that that rule should hold for each $j$, which uniquely specifies $J_B$. $J_B$ takes in $B$-coordinates and returns the corresponding vector in $U$.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the matrix for case 2 should be different from that for case 1.

Though they have same entries  the way they have to be used  is different.

Let A1 and A2 denote the matrices in these two cases.

Suppose we want to know the value $t(v)$ in standard basis, for some $v\in V$

In the first case ,
express $v$ in standard basis, call that co-ordinate vector $[v]_1$ then multiply with A1 for case 1.

In the second case express $v$  in non-standard basis getting a different co-ordinate vector $[v]_2$, then multiply with $A2$.

Now compare the results and see what you get.